# css hovering lists with positioning

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, flexbox

I'm having an issue with some css on my hover of my list element.

When I go to hover it seems two things happen.

1) When I mouse over the list the width of the element expands like it should, but one of the elements gets pushed into its place, I guess because I have it set to absolute, but I'm not sure what other way around that.

2) When I take the mouse off it seems like all the elements come out of place.

What I want is to be able to hover on each list and for it to expand with text and not have any of the other elements move.

Here's the code:

```css
.menu-right {
  right: 0
}
.icon-steeringWheel {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.visualiser-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}
.visualiser-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li .visualiser-menu-btn {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 11px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li .visualiser-menu-btn span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li .visualiser-menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="visualiser-menu menu-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" id="selectModel" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel ui-"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: another good candidate for Stack Snippets: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Answer (score 2):

When you give the list item `position: absolute` on hover, you remove it from the document flow. This means that other list items don't even know it exists, so they occupy the hovered item's original space. That's why you're getting the shifting.

Without getting into heavy restructuring of your code, you need to compensate for the lost space when the list item is hovered.

One method is to define a height for the list item at the same time the hover occurs.

Here's an example (on the first list item only).

```css
.menu-right {
  right: 0;
}
.icon-steeringWheel {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.visualiser-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}
.visualiser-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* NEW */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li .visualiser-menu-btn {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 11px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li .visualiser-menu-btn span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.visualiser-menu ul li:first-child:hover {
  height: 65px;
}
/* NEW */

.visualiser-menu ul li:first-child .visualiser-menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="visualiser-menu menu-right">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" id="selectModel" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel ui-"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="visualiser-menu-btn" href="#"><span class="icon-steeringWheel"></span> this is some text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```